# WorksheetFunction to Application.Worksheetfunction

Tags: python, excel, vba

I've got a rather complex formula at hand. So far, I've been using `Range.Formula2R1C1`, however it is painfully slow.

The original formula in `ws.Cell (3, 14)` are:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(IFERROR(MATCH(tblPO[PO_MAT];IF(B3=tblPO[PROJECT];tblPO[PO_MAT];"");0);"")=MATCH(ROW(tblPO[PO_MAT]);ROW(tblPO[PO_MAT]));tblPO[PO_MAT];""))
```

**Code**

```
Public Function WriteComplexFormulas()

    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PO")
    
    
    Dim obj As ListObject
    Set obj = ws.ListObjects("tblOrders")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    
 
    ws.Cells(3, 14).Formula2R1C1 = "=TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,IF(IFERROR(MATCH(tblPO[PO_MAT],IF(RC[-12]=tblPO[PROJECT],tblPO[PO_MAT],""""),0),"""")=MATCH(ROW(tblPO[PO_MAT]),ROW(tblPO[PO_MAT])),tblPO[PO_MAT],""""))"

    
    For j = 1 To obj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        ws.Cells(j + 2, 14).Value = ws.Cells(j + 2, 14).Value
    Next j
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Function
```

Table orders for one particular SO looks as follows:
[image]

The result of the current worksheet function returns all results in column `'PO_MAT'` for each `'PROJECT'` as a string: `"RELAYXX1, RELAYXY2, RELAYXZ3"`

Now, the reason for the longtime is of course the very resource-heavy formula. `ws.cell(3,14)` are the first cell in a table. The formula are thus written (autofilled) down to some 2500 rows of data. This takes processing time for sure.

I'm stuck as to how to proceed to make it run faster, as `Application.Worksheetfunction` does not have an `"IF"-statement`.

Any pointers on how I could replace this function with VBA? If of any help, I achieved the same result in Python:

```
def modifyDict(df):
        df['PROJECT'] = (df['SD_DOC'] + '-' +  df['SD_ITM'])
        df= df[['PROJECT', 'PO_MAT']]
       
        df = pd.DataFrame(df)
        dict_ = df.groupby('PROJECT')['PO_MAT'].agg(list).to_dict()

        keys_values = dict_.items()
        outputDict = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in keys_values}

        output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outputDict,orient='index').reset_index()
        output.columns = np.arange(len(output.columns))

        output.rename(index=str).index
        output.columns = ['PROJECT','PO_MAT']

        return output
```

**To clarify the requirement**

Desired result is a string, containing all matches for a given key in a table.

The two tables are:

[image]

Column 'Materials Ordered' illustrates the desired output: a concatenation of all values associated with each key found in the rightmost table, linked with the leftmost tables keys.

Comment: Hi, in my opinion if you are using tables then probably fastest way would be to add next column with those calculations in power query not excel function. If you don't want to create new table in power querry you can add python to excel [Setting up R and Python in Microsoft Excel-Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBipqB_RRAk)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not an option to use xlwings. I will take a shot at PowerQuery.. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I achieved the same result in Python"? Does it take the same time, or is faster? Do you want suggesting a need of a similar code transposed in VBA, or something else? If something similar, you should edit your question and better explain what you try accomplishing. At least pictures showing the existing situation (the two sheets/tables) and what you need. Better explained in terms of processing way. I do not like to deduce that looking to the formula or your Python code...

Comment: Hi, thanks. Will edit the question. But in short: Achieving the same result as in same output table. Processing time in Python is almost 10 times as fast. Same output, different runtime

Comment: I do not see any new element able to clarify what you try accomplishing...

Comment: Added new elements for clarification

Comment: So, there are two tables to be processed. The first contain a (unique) projects enumeration in column "PROJECT" and the second one more such projects (not unique) in column (also)  "PROJECT" and strings to be returned in column "PO_Mat".  The second table name should be "tblPO". The code should return as fast as possible all projects occurrences in the second table, in a comma separated string. Will this understanding cover what you need accomplishing?

Comment: If my above assumptions are correct, it should return in column "Materials Ordered" of the first table... And the second table is placed in sheet "PO"...

Comment: Hi, your assumptions are correct. Each key (PROJET) may occur multiple times in "tblPO" - one occurrence for each PO_MAT. Each match should then be returned in a comma-separated list to column "Materials Ordered" in table 1. All occurrences of "PROJECT" in the first table are unique. The second table is located in sheet "PO".

Comment: Please, try tagging me (@FaneDuru) when try answering my comments... Otherwise, I am not notified and I can see your comments/answers only if I come here, knowing that your tagging habit is not the best... :) OK, I will prepare an answer. Not just now, but after some minutes.

Comment: Please, test the code I supplied and send some feedback... You receive notifications because you are the question issuer. If you will comment bellow my answer, no need to tag me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next solution. It should be very fast, using arrays, a dictionary and dropping the processed array content at once. It shouldn't be used as a UDF function  (called from a cell). You should run the code as it is and it will bring what (I understood) is needed, in the appropriate table column:

```
Sub bringProjectsMaterials()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, tblOrd As ListObject, tblPO As ListObject
  Dim arrPr1, arrPr2, arrO, arrMat, arrMatO, dict As Object, i As Long
  
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders")
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PO")
  Set tblOrd = ws.ListObjects("tblOrders")
  Set tblPO = ws2.ListObjects("tblPO")

  arrPr1 = tblOrd.ListColumns("PROJECT").DataBodyRange.Value2 'place the ranges in arrays, for faster iteration/processing
  arrPr2 = tblPO.ListColumns("PROJECT").DataBodyRange.Value2
  arrMat = tblPO.ListColumns("PO_MAT2").DataBodyRange.Value2
  
  'build the dictionary of unique orders in tblPO with PROJECT as keys and PO_MAT as strings to be returned
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrPr2)
        If Not dict.Exists(arrPr2(i, 1)) Then
           dict(arrPr2(i, 1)) = arrMat(i, 1)
        Else
            dict(arrPr2(i, 1)) = dict(arrPr2(i, 1)) & "," & arrMat(i, 1)
        End If
  Next i
  'fill the array to keep the processed result:
  ReDim arrMatO(1 To UBound(arrPr1), 1 To 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrPr1)
        arrMatO(i, 1) = dict(arrPr1(i, 1))
  Next i
  'drop the processed array content in the necessary column:
   tblOrd.ListColumns("Materials Ordered").DataBodyRange.Value2 = arrMatO
End Sub
MsgBox "Ready..."
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @FaneDuru . This perfectly resolved the issue at hand, and wors lightning fast ( ~70 seconds to under 1 second). It also helped me improve my understanding of dictionaries/arrays in VBA.

Comment: @Havard Kleven Glad I could help! I tried commenting to make the code understandable, even for the ones not too familiar with VBA. But if something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarification... For instance, a content of an array must be dropped in a range **having the same number of rows and columns like the used array**. In the above code it (only) happens that the range to receive its content is appropriate (using `DataBodyRange` of the same table). You may drop its content in a cell, but using `cellRange.Resize(ubound(arrMatO), ubound(arrMatO, 2))  arrMatO`...

Comment: @Havard Kleven Also iterating  between a dictionary keys/items may be interesting... :) Now, it only happened to have the necessary dictionary keys in another array. Most of the time, the built array should be dropped in another range and should be loaded in such an iteration loop.

Comment: I see - yes, the code was well commented, and "less advanced" that I first feared it would be utilizing arrays/dicts - thanks again.